# Prevent commands during client.wait_for() discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've encountered a problem with `client.wait_for()`.

```
while True:
      msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
```

While running an infinite loop, when I type in the same command, there is another "instance" of that command running.

Is there a way to prevent the usage of commands during the `client.wait_for()` response?

I tried with `startswith('prefix')` but It's not working, the commands execute anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Dominik! Are your commands within an `on_message` event, or are they in `@client.command` functions? Thanks in advance

Comment: My commands are in the `@client.command` functions, in cogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit the usage of ONE command so that it can to allow a certain number of invocations at the same time, use the decorator [`max_concurrency`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=max_concurrency#discord.ext.commands.max_concurrency).

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks a lot, It will surely help with my problem :D!

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable `commandsDisabled = True` before the wait_for and set it to `False` after. Then check for this variable in every command

Comment: That sounds like a good fix, but I'm not sure if It's the right way to do it :D However, I'll definitely try it! Thanks!